# Flutter/Dart: How to correctly implement multi-chip filtering with if/else

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a multi-chip filtering to display **stores** (e.g. Zara, H&M, HomeDepot) from a list based on the **category** of stores the user selects to be displayed (e.g. Fashion, Outdoors, DYI). That part works.

Note: only one instance per store is displayed, i.e. if one store belongs to several categories, it will be displayed just once.

**What doesn't work**: when the page first loads or if NO categories are selected for filtering, I want to display all available stores. Seems as if it should be a simple if/else in the filtering, but I can't get it to work. I simply get a blank page instead. Any ideas from anyone a bit smarter?? Below is a reproduced code snippet that you can copy & paste to play around with.

[Visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1LKy.png)

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_filtering/categories_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_filtering/stores_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => Stores(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => Categories(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 24),
              Text('Categories', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2),
              CategoryFiltersSection(),
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryFiltersSection extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoryFiltersSectionState createState() => _CategoryFiltersSectionState();
}

class _CategoryFiltersSectionState extends State<CategoryFiltersSection> {
  // For filtering the list, I've created two lists. The categories list, which contains all the categories, and the selected categories list, which will contain the categories selected (for filtering).
  List<Category> categoriesList = [];
  List<Category> selectedCategoriesList = [];

  // Preparing list of stores to be filtered
  List<Store> allStores;
  Set<Store> storesToDisplay = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    final loadedCategories = Provider.of<Categories>(context, listen: false).items;
    categoriesList = loadedCategories;

    final loadedStores = Provider.of<Stores>(context, listen: false).items;
    allStores = loadedStores;

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    filterStores(allStores);

    return Column(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
                MultiSelectChip(
                  categoriesList,
                  onSelectionChanged: (selectedCategories) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedCategoriesList = selectedCategories;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 200,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: storesToDisplay.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text('${storesToDisplay.elementAt(index).title}');
              }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void filterStores(allStores) {
    storesToDisplay.clear();

    // If categories are selected for filtering, display relevant stores
    if (selectedCategoriesList != null) {
      // Extract ids of selected categories
      print('Selected categories: $selectedCategoriesList');
      final List<String> idsOfSelectedCategories = selectedCategoriesList.map((category) => category.id).toList();
      print('Ids of selected categories: $idsOfSelectedCategories');

      // Get stores in the selected categories and updates stores to be displayed
      Set<Store> storesInSelectedCategories = getStoresFromSelectedCategories(allStores, idsOfSelectedCategories);
      setState(() {
        storesToDisplay = storesInSelectedCategories;
      });

      // Else if no categories are selected for filtering, display all stores by default
    } else {
      setState(() {
        storesToDisplay = allStores;
      });
    }
  }
}

Set<Store> getStoresFromSelectedCategories(List<Store> allStores, List<String> idsOfSelectedCategories) {
  Set<Store> allStoresFromCategory = {};
  for (var categoryId in idsOfSelectedCategories) {
    var storesMatched = allStores.where((store) => store.categoryIds.contains(categoryId)).toList();
    allStoresFromCategory.addAll(storesMatched);
  }
  return allStoresFromCategory;
}

class MultiSelectChip extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Category> categoriesList;
  final Function(List<Category>) onSelectionChanged;

  MultiSelectChip(this.categoriesList, {this.onSelectionChanged});

  @override
  _MultiSelectChipState createState() => _MultiSelectChipState();
}

class _MultiSelectChipState extends State<MultiSelectChip> {
  List<Category> selectedCategories = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: _buildSelectionsList(),
    );
  }

  _buildSelectionsList() {
    List<Widget> selections = [];

    widget.categoriesList.forEach((category) {
      selections.add(Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        child: FilterChip(
          label: Text(category.title),
          selected: selectedCategories.contains(category),
          onSelected: (selected) {
            setState(() {
              selectedCategories.contains(category) ? selectedCategories.remove(category) : selectedCategories.add(category);
              widget.onSelectionChanged(selectedCategories);
            });
          },
        ),
      ));
    });

    return selections;
  }
}
```

**stores_provider.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Store {
  Store({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.categoryIds,
  });

  final String id;
  final String title;
  final List<String> categoryIds;

  @override
  String toString() => 'title: $title, categoryIds: $categoryIds';
}


class Stores with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Store> _items = [
    Store(
      id: 's1',
      title: 'Store 1',
      categoryIds: ['c1', 'c2', 'c7'],
    ),
    Store(
      id: 's2',
      title: 'Store 2',
      categoryIds: ['c1', 'c3', 'c7'],
    ),
    Store(
      id: 's3',
      title: 'Store 3',
      categoryIds: [ 'c1', 'c3', 'c4', 'c9'],
    ),
    Store(
      id: 's4',
      title: 'Store 4',
      categoryIds: ['c1', 'c4', 'c5', 'c9'],
    ),
    Store(
      id: 's5',
      title: 'Store 5',
      categoryIds: ['c1', 'c5', 'c6'],
    ),
    Store(
      id: 's6',
      title: 'Store 6',
      categoryIds: [ 'c1', 'c8', 'c2'],
    ),
    Store(
      id: 's7',
      title: 'Store 7',
      categoryIds: [ 'c1', 'c8', 'c10'],
    ),
    Store(
      id: 's8',
      title: 'Store 8',
      categoryIds: [ 'c1', 'c8', 'c10'],
    ),
    Store(
      id: 's9',
      title: 'Store 9',
      categoryIds: [ 'c1', 'c8', 'c10'],
    ),
    Store(
      id: 's10',
      title: 'Store 10',
      categoryIds: [ 'c1', 'c8', 'c10'],
    ),
  ];

  List<Store> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

}
```

**categories_provider.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Category {
  final String id;
  final String title;

  const Category({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
  });

  @override
  String toString() => '$title';
}


class Categories with ChangeNotifier {

  List<Category> _items = [
    Category(
      id: 'c1',
      title: 'Fashion',
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c2',
      title: 'Health & Beauty',
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c3',
      title: 'Tech & Electronics',
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c4',
      title: 'Sports',
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c5',
      title: 'Outdoors',
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c6',
      title: 'Baby Products',
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c7',
      title: 'Travel',
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c8',
      title: 'Halloween'
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c9',
      title: 'Food',
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c10',
      title: 'Casino',
    ),
  ];

  List<Category> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error when working with chips? In run output in IDE.

Comment: @fartem I've amended the code. I've run the code in Android Studio with no problems.

Comment: You have an error messages in logs?

Answer (score 0):

Since you instantiate the category list as an empty list and assign it from the value of `MultiChipSelect` (which itself will always be at least an empty list), it will never be null. As such, the following condition will always be true:

```dart
if (selectedCategoriesList != null)
```

Instead, check whether or not it is empty:

```dart
if (selectedCategoriesList.isNotEmpty)
```

Comment: thanks but I've tried both `if (selectedCategoriesList.isNotEmpty)` and `if (selectedCategoriesList.length == 0)` and neither work. Totally confusing!

Comment: @Camron Is the code in the else block running at all?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. There were two things that needed to be corrected in the `filterStores(allStores)` function.

1. In the **if** statement, the condition needed to be corrected to `if (selectedCategoriesList != null && selectedCategoriesList.isNotEmpty)` so that it ensures both that it's not null and empty.
2. In the **else** statement, the correct code for adding the `allStores`, which is of type `List<Store>` to `storesToDisplay`, which is of type `Set<Store>`, is `storesToDisplay.addAll(allStores)`.

All in all, the corrected `filterStores(allStores)` function should be this:

```
  void filterStores(allStores) {
    storesToDisplay.clear();

    // If categories are selected for filtering, display relevant stores
    if (selectedCategoriesList != null && selectedCategoriesList.isNotEmpty) {

      // Extract ids of selected categories
      final List<String> idsOfSelectedCategories = selectedCategoriesList.map((category) => category.id).toList();

      // Get stores in the selected categories and update stores to be displayed
      Set<Store> storesInSelectedCategories = getStoresFromSelectedCategories(allStores, idsOfSelectedCategories);
      setState(() {
        storesToDisplay = storesInSelectedCategories;
      });

      // Else if no categories are selected for filtering, display all stores by default
    } else {

      setState(() {
        storesToDisplay.addAll(allStores);
      });
    }
  }
```